# CSS Transform offset varies with text length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

I have set up a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/cYyFj/) that has 5 floating `<div>`s with rotated text of varying length. I am wondering if there is a way to have a CSS class that can handle centering of all text regardless of length. At the moment I have to create a class for each length of characters in my stylesheet. This could get too messy. I have also noticed that the offsets get screwd up is I increase or decrease the size of the wrapping `<div>`.

I will be adding these classes to divs through jQuery, but I still have to set up each class for cross-browser compatibility.

```
.transform3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 65% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 65% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 65% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 65% 100%;
    transform-origin: 65% 100%;    
}
.transform4 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 70% 110%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 70% 110%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 70% 110%;
    -o-transform-origin: 70% 110%;
    transform-origin: 70% 110%;
}
.transform5 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 80% 120%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 80% 120%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 80% 120%;
    -o-transform-origin: 80% 120%;
    transform-origin: 80% 120%;
}
.transform6 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 85% 136%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 85% 136%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 85% 136%;
    -o-transform-origin: 85% 136%;
    transform-origin: 85% 136%;
}
.transform7 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 90% 150%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 90% 150%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 90% 150%;
    -o-transform-origin: 90% 150%;
    transform-origin: 90% 150%;
}
```

*Note:* The offset values I set were eye-balled.

---

### Update

Although I would like this handled with a stylesheet, I believe that I will have to calculate the transformations of the CSS in JavaScript.

I have created the following [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/geA27/) to demonstrate dynamic transformations. In this demo, the user can adjust the `font-size` of the `.v_text` class and as long as the length of the text does not exceed the `.v_text_wrapper` height, the text should be vertically aligned in the center, but be aware that I have to adjust the `magicOffset` value.

<strike>Well, I just noticed that this does not work in iOS...</strike> Thanks @Dinesh Kumar DJ

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geA27/11/ updated the jsfiddle

Comment: I will set your update as the baseline. Why does it matter if you calculate the offset before you add the element to the document?

Comment: the elements position,width etc is not calculated until it is added to the dom

Comment: i think this is what u need, http://jsfiddle.net/geA27/15/, you can optimize the code as you need, thanks

Comment: I feel dumb for not calling using `text-align:center` to handle centering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/fgekh

```
#output1,
#output2{
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rotate {
  //remove this line if using js
  transform: translateY(150px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.v_text_wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #AAA;
  border: solid #222 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#output2 .v_text_wrapper {
  height: 170px;
}

.v_text {
  color: #444;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;

  width: 150px; //remove this line if using js
  height: 100px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

No need for JS and dynamic offseting. You can set all `<div>`'s containing text at same width and height as wrappers, rotate them around top left corner (could be any corner) and then use translateY to position them back inside wrapper (this assumes that wrapper dimensions are always the same and known value).

I added extra `<p>` element around text and did vertical centering using this method: 
http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

**Edit:** I updated pen in case wrapper `<div>` changes size. Since `<div>`'s are rotated, their witdh becames height and vice versa so if wrapper has dimension 100x150 then child has to be 150x100.

```
$('.v_text_wrapper').each(function(){
  var x = $(this).css("height");
  var text = $(this).children('.v_text');
  text.css({"transform":"translateY("+x+") rotate(-90deg)", "width":x});
});
```